# Polygon boundary interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation, polygon, spatial-interpolation

I have a polygon dataframe:
[image]

With vertice coordinates:

```
43740.95    40726.46
43741.36    40720.19
43742.67    40729.28
43743.99    40716.16
43745.52    40730.97
43748.72    40714.19
43748.72    40731.14
43748.72    40714.19
43752.23    40714.76
43752.86    40729.43
43755.27    40716.68
43756.77    40723.24
43757.19    40719.73
```

Is there any way in R to interpolate spatial objects such that the boundary could be more smooth?

Comment: I would take a look at the smoothr package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smoothr/vignettes/smoothr.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [smoothr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/smoothr/smoothr.pdf) package for smoothing an sf object. I created an example based on your data where `data` is your sample that you provided. Because your polygon is an irregular shape, the smoothing is going to also look irregular. You can adjust the smoothing as need be or change the smoothing algorithm. However, a spline will probably work in your case.

```
library(sf)
library(smoothr)

smooth_poly <- data %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords=c("x", "y")) %>% 
  st_union() %>% 
  st_convex_hull() %>% 
  smooth(method='spline', n=1000)
```

[image]